# Am I using "NOT IN" correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, case, hierarchical-data

I'm trying the HackerRank problem linked [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem).

I'm curious as to why my attempted solution does not return any rows for the binary tree's leaves. Here's my full query:

```
SELECT N, 'Root'
FROM BST
WHERE ISNULL(P)

UNION

SELECT N, 'Inner'
FROM BST
WHERE N IN (SELECT P FROM BST) AND NOT ISNULL(P)

UNION

SELECT N, 'Leaf'
FROM BST
WHERE N NOT IN (SELECT P FROM BST)

ORDER BY N
```

It seems to me like my approach to identifying the leaves is correct - a leaf is defined as a node that is not a parent. However, when I try the `SELECT N, 'Leaf' ...` query on its own, I get no output.

Can anyone spot my error? Am I using the `NOT IN` statement correctly?

edit: Just to clarify, N is the value of the node, and the corresponding P is its parent. N and P are both integers.

Comment: `not in(...)` is always a problem if NULL can be encountered within the parentheses

Comment: @Strawberry got it, I'll try to do that. Is fiddle etc. substantially preferred over the SQL hackerrank submission interface?

Comment: 'Substantially' would be an understatement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the leaf query, you get nothing:

```
mysql> select n, 'Leaf' from bst where n not in (select p from bst);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

The reason is that the result of the subquery includes NULL:

```
mysql> select distinct p from bst;
+------+
| p    |
+------+
| NULL |
|    1 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
```

The comparison `N not in (NULL, 1, 3, 4)` is bound to return no matches, because of the NULL. This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE NOT (N = NULL OR N = 1 OR N = 3 OR N = 4)
```

But any comparison to NULL is NULL, not false. You can get true/false for the other terms, but not the first term. This simplifies to:

```
WHERE NOT (NULL OR FALSE OR FALSE OR FALSE)
```

Which in turn simplifies to:

```
WHERE NOT (NULL)
```

But the negation of NULL is also NULL, not true. Therefore the condition in your query is bound to block out all nodes, whether they are leafs or not.

You can fix this by eliminating the NULLs:

```
mysql> select n, 'Leaf' from bst where n not in (select p from bst where not isnull(p));
+---+------+
| n | Leaf |
+---+------+
| 2 | Leaf |
| 5 | Leaf |
| 6 | Leaf |
+---+------+
```

---

You should also look into using [recursive CTE queries in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples) if you have this sort of data:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (N, Label) AS
( 
  SELECT bst.N, CAST('Root' AS CHAR(20)) FROM bst WHERE ISNULL(P)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT bst.N, IF(below.P IS NULL, 'Leaf', 'Inner') FROM bst JOIN cte ON bst.P=cte.N
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bst AS below ON bst.N=below.P
)
SELECT DISTINCT N, Label FROM cte

+------+-------+
| N    | Label |
+------+-------+
|    1 | Root  |
|    2 | Leaf  |
|    3 | Inner |
|    4 | Inner |
|    5 | Leaf  |
|    6 | Leaf  |
+------+-------+
```

Comment: Got it, this explains it. I'll change the code to exclude NULL in the WHERE clause. Thanks Bill!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
select n, 
    case when p is null then 'root'
         when not exists (select 1 from bst b1 where b1.p = b.n) then 'leaf'
         else 'inner'
    end as res
from bst b
```

This phrases as:

- if `p` is `null`, the node has no parent, hence it is a (the?) root
- if there is no node whose `p` is equal to the `n` of the current node, then the node has no child: it is a leaf
- else, it is an inner node

Note that, in theory at least, a node could be both a root and a leaf; the challenge question does not mention that possibility. If this ever happens, the query would flag it as a root (because that's the first branch that would match in the `case` expression).