# Why does MySQL exhibit different behavior on 'IN' and 'NOT IN' queries?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 equal queris, the only difference is IN and NOT IN.
**First One: **

```
select distinct p.id, p.created_at
from dkms_promotions p
         inner join dkms_users u on u.id = p.created_by
         INNER JOIN dkms_promotion_stats ps on ps.promotion_id = p.id
where (ps.seller_id != 1 or
       u.role in ('marketplace_admin', 'retail_admin', 'retail', 'retail_fashion_admin', 'premium_brand'))
  and p.nature in ('normal', 'lightening_deal', 'incredible_offer', 'mega_promotion')
and p.status not in ('ended', null, '')
order by p.id desc
limit 0,20;
```

**Second One: **

```
select distinct p.id, p.created_at
from dkms_promotions p
         inner join dkms_users u on u.id = p.created_by
         INNER JOIN dkms_promotion_stats ps on ps.promotion_id = p.id
where (ps.seller_id != 1 or
       u.role in ('marketplace_admin', 'retail_admin', 'retail', 'retail_fashion_admin', 'premium_brand'))
  and p.nature in ('normal', 'lightening_deal', 'incredible_offer', 'mega_promotion')
  AND p.status in ('draft', 'pending', 'approved', 'rejected', 'active')
order by p.id desc
limit 0,20;
```

status is an enum column with below difinition:

```
status enum ('draft', 'pending', 'approved', 'rejected', 'active', 'ended') null
```

but MySQL choose 2 diferent execution plan, but the second one is better by far.

Q1: why MySQL chooses different execution plan?
Q2: is this behaviour just for enum column?

I ckecked some same examples and got this behaviour again, thay must be the same.

Comment: Hossein selection of a query plan is a very complex task. in which the Query plan engine takes a couple of factors including affinity of data, indexes, and many statistics used internally. max we can do is use EXPLAIN statement to understand what the query plan looks like and proceed/optimise further.

Comment: yes, you are correct but this is a straightforward task, for example when I use "!=" for one element and "IN" for all other elements of the column, MySQL chooses a bad execution plan for the first scenario.
we have more expectations from such a big DB like MySQL.

Comment: You are asking about "2 different execution plans", and you do not even show them?  Also, please, add the output of your `SHOW CREATE TABLE ....` for the involved tables. (see: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) )

Comment: Probably the output of: `select status, count(*) from dkms_promotions group by status;` might show why MySQL chooses to use another execution plan....This because one `status` is not occurring, and another `status` had many occurrences. (But we do not know your data, so only guessing can be done)

Comment: `NOT IN (...)` has some effects that you may not expect when one of the values is NULL. See my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451958/am-i-using-not-in-correctly/64453938#64453938

Comment: the assumption "thay must be the same" (besides the spelling error ) is simply incorrect.

Comment: I added the status definition. so these 2 types of writing the status part of the query are equal.
I do not understand why you are looking for more information. @Luuk

Comment: I also change the "NOT IN" to
`p.status is not null and p.status not in ('ended', '')`
to avoid NULL problem that you mentioned, but still, we get same execution plan as before.

Comment: @hosseinaghaei: The indexes that do, or do not, exist using the field `status`, and the contents of that field are one of the factors that is determining which access path is found to be the most effective foe the execution to take place.